# Remove last li row border

Tags: html, css

I need to remove border bottom of last li row.
like this below image example[image]

Thank You in advance :)

jsfiddle.net/foLacgg3/1

Comment: Include your html codes here

Comment: here the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/foLacgg3/1/ @Valkyriee

Answer (score 2):

If, you don't want to rewrite code, you can use pseudo elements to the , and give it background of your page(this will only hide border from any of last elements inside ul)

```
ul {
   list-style: none;
   padding-left: 0;
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
}
ul:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background: #F3F5F6;
  /*(page background)*/
  width: 100%;
}

https://jsfiddle.net/foLacgg3/2/
```

Comment: @Ostap Mushynskyy this is pretty awesome hack thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code snippet you posted after my first answer:

- it seems you either have either three or four elements per row with a breaking point at around 740 pixels in between the two options.
- it seems you have 9 list elements in the grid.
- if you don´t know the number of li elements - then I can help you if you can use SASS instead of CSS.

Therefore, presuming you know the number of li elements - let´s say your code is like this:

```
    @media only screen and (max-width:740px) { 
ul.menu li:nth-child(n+7) { border:none;}

}
```

And for other screen sizes:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:740px) { 
  ul.menu li:last-child {border:none;}
}
```

Comment: i want to remove last row not last child :/

Comment: @ITbug - see the above edit. Is the number of li elements defined? If not, can you use Sass instead of CSS?